# How to properly setup axios client with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is what I have so far:

```
type TRequest = {
    url: string;
    method?: EMethodTypes;
    params?: TParams;
    body?: TBody;
};

export const httpClient = async <Result>(
    { url, method = EMethodTypes.GET, params = {}, body = {} }: TRequest
): Promise<AxiosResponse<Result>> =>
    await axios({
        url,
        method,
        params,
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      });
```

But when I attempt to make a request as,

```
const { user, token } = await httpClient<{user: TUser; token: string}>({
  url: apiRoutes.POST.AUTH.LOGIN,
  method: EMethodTypes.POST,
  body: formData,
});
```

I get an error,

```
const { user, token } = await httpClient<{user: TUser; token: string}>({
        ^^^^
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<{ user: any; token: string; }>'.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, considering that I *do* have both of those properties indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all http-clients, the response body is a nested property inside the response (in this case `data`), modify your code as demonstrated below:

```
const { data: { user, token } } = await httpClient<{ user: TUser; token: string }>({
  url: apiRoutes.POST.AUTH.LOGIN,
  method: EMethodTypes.POST,
  body: formData,
})
```

Or optionally:

```
const { user, token } = (await httpClient<{ user: TUser; token: string }>({
  url: apiRoutes.POST.AUTH.LOGIN,
  method: EMethodTypes.POST,
  body: formData,
})).data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with axios but from types:
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L76

it means that if you want to get `user` you need to take it from `AxiosResponse.data`.